# SwiftUI : NavigationLink and the show Sheet Button in the List item works same time

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a list item with some text stuff, `navigationLink` and button to show `.sheet`.When I click on either navigation link or show sheet button both navigation destination and the sheet appear.How to avoid this behaviour?

Note: This is minimal produceable code.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var shouldSheetShow:Bool = false;

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List{
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text("Some Text Stuff")
                    NavigationLink(
                        destination: Text("navigation link"),
                        label: {
                            Text("Navigate To some view")
                                .background(Color.green)
                        })

                    Button(action: {
                        self.shouldSheetShow = true
                    }, label: {
                        HStack{
                            Text("Show sheet")
                        }
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        .sheet(isPresented: $shouldSheetShow, content: {
                            Text("sheet")
                        })

                    })
                }
                .frame(width: 300, height: 150, alignment: .center)
                .background(Color.gray)
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: List Item]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to replace the `Button` with `Text` plus an `onTapGesture`

Replace

```
Button(action: {
        self.shouldSheetShow = true
    }, label: {
        HStack{
            Text("Show sheet")
        }
        .background(Color.blue)
        .sheet(isPresented: $shouldSheetShow, content: {
            Text("sheet")
        })

    })
```

with

```
Text("Show sheet")
        .background(Color.blue)
        .sheet(isPresented: $shouldSheetShow, content: {
            Text("sheet")
        })
        .onTapGesture {
            self.shouldSheetShow = true
        }
```

Comment: It works, can you please explain the theoretical reason to that issue? I mean why we cannot use my combination inside list item.because my combination working properly  when it is not inside a list.

Comment: Honestly I don't know the proper reason but I guess that particularly in a List the tappable area of the NavigationItem  is extended to the whole *cell* and affects also the Button area.